# SQL Server Log Backup

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In Microsoft SQL Server I should take log backup twice to free up LDF space. Why did this happen?
Can anyone help me?

In fact, I use full model recovery and have a full backup.
I want to say that I am sure that full model recovery is active. But when I take a log backup from the database, the space of the LDF file is not freed, until I take a log backup for the second time in a row, and the space is freed.

Answer (score 4):

When you take a log backup, only inactive Virtual Log Files (VLFs) within the LDF can be backed up and truncated - therefore, if you have an active/open transaction consuming a VLF near the end of the file, the file cannot be truncated.

This document provides some common reasons truncation might be delayed:

- [Factors that can delay log truncation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#FactorsThatDelayTruncation)